# shared preference login activity

Tags: android, database, authentication, sharedpreferences, android-sharedpreferences

i am trying to save the user login credentials in one screen (login.java) and trying to obtain that when the user login, and trying to obtain it  on another activity (loggedin.java) but its not happening.

```
login.java
 b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            {
                SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("Mypref", 0);
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();

                {
                    editor.putString("email", e1.getText().toString());
                    editor.putString("password", e2.getText().toString());
                    editor.commit();
                    String email = pref.getString("email", null);
                    t.setText(email);
                    //Log.e("email",email);
                }
            }



loggedin.java
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.accinfo);
    t1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
    t2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);
    SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences("MYPref", 0);
    String email = pref.getString("email", null);
    String password = pref.getString("password", null);
    t1.setText(email);
    t2.setText(password);
}}
```

the output is coming NULL,instead of users credentials

Comment: MYPref and MYpref  P and y changed in getSharedPref spell mistake

Comment: change "MYPref" to "Myrpref", you needthe same name

Comment: Off-topic > simple typographical error.

Comment: Check this link http://junalontherun.com/2011/11/11/android-basic-login-example-with-shared-preference/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should keep in mind the names you give as this is case sensitive.

> MYPref - Mypref

Answer (score 1):

You have two different names when you call the SharedPreferences, check the strings and maybe use a global variable so you can't fail the input :)

> MYPref - Mypref

Anyway if you need to use them all over your application, you can create a class (.java file) and use static values, example:

```
public class LoggedUser{
    public static String email;
    public static String password;

    //getters and setters

}
```

If you assign them a value when the user logs in, you will have them filled all over the application without calling every time the sharedPrefs

Answer (score 0):

A simple and elegant solution is to use a very simple library [TinyDB](https://github.com/kcochibili/TinyDB--Android-Shared-Preferences-Turbo) in android, which is nothing but an abstraction over the Shared Preferences.

You can initialise it in your activity's `onCreate()` method like this:

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(this);
```

And then use it like this:

```
tinydb.putString("userName", "john");
String currentUser = tinydb.getString("userName");
```

Hope it helps.